# Weird output using a switch-statement

Tags: c++, class, object, switch-statement

I just made a program with a Class that allows you to calculate with rational numbers simply. So for unterstanding here is my code:
(Dont ask why its Relational instead of Rational im just dumb naming things)

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Relational.h"

using namespace std;

char Relational::lastOperation = 'z';

void main() {

Relational a(4, 5), b(3, 17), c;

c.inverse(a); c.outLast();
c.add(a, b); c.outLast();
c.sub(a, b); c.outLast();
c.mult(a, b); c.outLast();
c.div(a, b); c.outLast();

system("pause");
}
```

Relational.h:

```
class Relational
{
private:
int numerator, denominator;

public:
Relational(int n, int d);
Relational(int n) :numerator(n), denominator(0) {}
Relational() : numerator(0), denominator(0) {}

void setNumerator(int n) { numerator = n; }
void setDenominator(int d) {
    if (d<0)
    {
        numerator = -numerator;
        denominator = -d;
    }
    else denominator = d;
}
int getNumerator() const { return numerator; }
int getDenominator() const { return denominator; }
void out() const { std::cout << "\tNumerator" << numerator << "\n\tDenominator " << denominator << std::endl; }
void outLast();
int inverse(Relational a);
int add(Relational a, Relational b);
int sub(Relational a, Relational b);
int mult(Relational a, Relational b);
int div(Relational a, Relational b);

private:

void shorten();

public:

static int anzahl;
static char lastOperation;

};
```

relational.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Relational.h"

using namespace std;

Relational::Relational(int n, int d) {

setNumerator(n);
setDenominator(d);
}

int Relational::inverse(Relational a) {

if (a.numerator != 0) {

    numerator = a.numerator;
    denominator = a.denominator;
    lastOperation = 'k';
    return 1;

}
else return 0;

}

int Relational::add(Relational a, Relational b) {

numerator = a.numerator*b.denominator + b.numerator*a.denominator;
denominator = a.denominator*b.denominator;
shorten();
lastOperation = 'a';
return 1;
}

int Relational::sub(Relational a, Relational b)
{
numerator = a.numerator*b.denominator - b.numerator*a.denominator;
denominator = a.denominator*b.denominator;
shorten();
lastOperation = 's';
return 1;
}

int Relational::mult(Relational a, Relational b)
{
numerator = a.numerator*b.numerator;
denominator = a.denominator*b.denominator;
shorten();
lastOperation = 'm';
return 1;
}

int Relational::div(Relational a, Relational b)
{
if (b.numerator != 0)
{
    numerator = a.numerator*b.denominator;
    denominator = a.denominator*b.numerator;
    if (denominator<0)
    {
        numerator = -numerator;
        denominator = -denominator;
    }
    shorten();
    lastOperation = 'd';
    return 1;

}
else return 0;
}

void Relational::shorten()
{
int x, y, rest;

x = numerator; y = denominator;
if (x<0) x = -x;

while (y>0)
{
    rest = x%y;
    x = y; y = rest;
}

numerator = numerator / x;
denominator = denominator / x;
}

void Relational::outLast() 
{
switch (lastOperation) {
case 'k': 
    std::cout << "Inverse:" << "\n\tNumerator: " << numerator << "\n\tDenominator: " << denominator << std::endl;
case 'a': 
    std::cout << "Sum:" << "\n\tNumerator: " << numerator << "\n\tDenominator: " << denominator << std::endl;
case 's': 
    std::cout << "Difference:" << "\n\tNumerator: " << numerator << "\n\tDenominator: " << denominator << std::endl;
case 'm': 
    std::cout << "Product:" << "\n\tNumerator: " << numerator << "\n\tDenominator: " << denominator << std::endl;
case 'd': 
    std::cout << "Quotient:" << "\n\tNumerator: " << numerator << "\n\tDenominator: " << denominator << std::endl;
default:
    out();
}
}
```

So the problem I have is the switch-statement.
When I run the code it should look like this:

`Inverse:
       Nominator: 5
       Denominator: 4
   Sum:
       Nominator: 83
       Denominator: 85
   Difference:
       Nominator: 53
       Denominator: 85
   Product:
       Nominator: 12
       Denominator: 85
   Quotient:
       Nominator: 68
       Denominator: 15`

Instead it looks like this:

`Inverse:
       Nominator: 5
       Denominator: 4
   Sum:
       Nominator: 5
       Denominator: 4
   Difference:
       Nominator: 5
       Denominator: 4
   Product:
       Nominator: 5
       Denominator: 4
   Quotient:
       Nominator: 5
       Denominator: 4
       Nominator: 5
       Denominator: 4
   Sum:
       Nominator: 83
       Denominator: 85
   Difference:
       Nominator: 83
       Denominator: 85
   Product:
       Nominator: 83
       Denominator: 85
   Quotient:
       Nominator: 83
       Denominator: 85
       Nominator: 83
       Denominator: 85
   Difference:
       Nominator: 53
       Denominator: 85
   Product:
       Nominator: 53
       Denominator: 85
   Quotient:
       Nominator: 53
       Denominator: 85
       Nominator: 53
       Denominator: 85
   Product:
       Nominator: 12
       Denominator: 85
   Quotient:
       Nominator: 12
       Denominator: 85
       Nominator: 12
       Denominator: 85
   Quotient:
       Nominator: 68
       Denominator: 15
       Nominator: 68
       Denominator: 15`

I have absolutly no idea why it gives me this output - I would appreciate your help very much :)

Comment: You forgot the `break` after each `case` in the `switch`

Comment: `Relational(int n) :numerator(n), denominator(0) {}` I don't think you really want this.

Comment: You can rename your class easily in your IDE/editor. No need to suffer from a bad name for the rest of your life.

Comment: @n.m sry im new to coding stuff - why do I not want this? OÖ

Comment: This has nothing to do with "coding". A rational number that is the same as the integer `n` is not `n/0`, it's `n/1`. You cannot divide by zero.